# Angular - fetch data from API

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to get data from flickr API. Precisely I need "photo" array from my URL.
It works when I getting to data in app.component and operate on any, but I know that this is not a good solution.

I Tried:

photo.ts:

```
  export class Photo {
    title: string;
    farm: number;
    secret: string;
    server: string;
    owner: string;
    id: string;
  };
```

app.component.ts:

```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    photos: Photo[];

    constructor(private http: HttpService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.getData();
    }

    getData() {
      this.http.getData().subscribe(data => {
        this.photos = data;
      });
    }
  }
```

and my main problem, http.service.ts:

```
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): Observable<Photo[]> {
    return this.http.get('https://api.flickr.com/path')
      .map(res => res.photos.photo);
  }
}
```

It seems to me that everything should work fine, but I get an error:

```
ERROR in src/app/http.service.ts(18,23): error TS2339: Property 'photos' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

Comment: what's the result of photos or res. did you check ?

Comment: `tap` before `map` to verify the result.

Comment: @Manjunath i edit the question and add console.log(res) img.

Comment: But wait, is it a runtime error or compile time errror?

Comment: its a compile time error

Comment: Yes, compile time error.

Comment: I am unsure if this resolves the issue. Try this. `this.http.get('https://api.flickr.com/path').map(res => res.json())
      .map(res => res.photos.photo);`

Comment: or this `this.http.get('https://api.flickr.com/path').pipe(map(res => res.json()),map(res => res.photos.photo));` The http service could be the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try implicitly setting res to 'any'

```
getData(): Observable<Photo[]> {
  return this.http.get('https://api.flickr.com/path')
    .map((res:any) => res.photos.photo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead in your photo.ts to match the response structure

```
export interface Photo {
    title: string,
    farm: number,
    secret: string,
    server: string,
    owner: string,
    id: string,
    isFriend: number,
    isFamily: number,
    isPublic: number
  };
```

And in your callback change to `this.photos = data.photos.photo`

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: You need to change aswell in your callback to this.photos = data.photos.photo

Answer (score -2):

This is very useful video with good example to fetch data from api using angularjs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lp8d4VZyhZc&t=666s

Comment: Hi, AngularJS is not the same as Angular (or Angular 2+)

Comment: They are very different. AnajuarJS can be embedded in any HTML code, cshtml, php, etc. But Angular mainly used as stand-alone frontend application.